# if else statement depending on array element (swift3)

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift3

My code below lists 2 things on a uitableview cell (a and b). I want a gif to be display just once on the cell where "a" is written.

```
  import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


var i1 = ["a","b"]
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return i1.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)


    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    cell.textLabel?.text = pets[indexPath.row]


     //what I am trying to do but does not work. if the cell reads a I want the cell to display a image.
       if i1[0] {
            cell.imageView?.loadGif(name: "ftf")
           }


    return cell
}}
```

Comment: what you mean with "a" is written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line here

```
if i1[0]
```

You aren't comparing it to anything.

For the set up you have with "a" as the first index, try this for the comparison

```
if i1[indexPath.row] == "a" {
    cell.imageView?.loadGif(name: "ftf")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How are you not getting a compiler error- String is not convertible to Bool?**

In Swift you need a boolean inside `if-block`. In your case that is

```
if "a" == i1[indexPath.row] {
}
```

Comment: I am getting a error i just type in what I was trying to do.

Comment: I have given you the reason for the error. You need to provide a boolean in if-block, in your case you need to do string comparison.